# AWS SQS pause consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Lets say for some reason I want to pause consuming reading messages from my SQS ... like a service on the client side will be down for maintanence. Can I pause from my SQS Listener?

```
  @SqsListener(value = "${aws.sqs.listener.myqueue}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void processMessage(MyObj myObj) {
        // do something with myObj
        // if db is down then throw error and pause reading from SQS

    }
```

I have run access some post that suggest to have a killSwitch but this is not ideal for production as it keeps consuming the messages and reposting to the queue.

Comment: What is running your consumer? Is it its only task?

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385901/how-can-i-freeze-an-sqs-queue-against-any-reads).

Comment: @palvarez, java client using spring cloud aws

Comment: @jarmod, yes saw that post ... it even talks about kill switch, as you can see in the post there are problems with that

Comment: You might consider disconnecting all event-driven consumers (e.g. Lambda functions) from the SQS queue and simply suppress all explicit receive calls from your app when the maintenance situation is detected (perhaps via SNS).

Comment: I was able to stop and start the queue consumption by autowiring simpleMessageListenerContainer and call its stop and start methods. Maybe there is a better way but it is working.